# infinite scroll not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml, lazy-loading

I am using infinite scroll plugin for my page, but after writing the code it doesn't seem to work.I scroll to the bottom of the page but the infinite scroll doesn't get fired.
I have included all the necessary files but still no use. I have included the xhtml page.
I have gone through the stackoverflow site but I was unable to find anything similar to my problem.

1)xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">


<h:head>
    <link href="Css/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        media="screen" />



<script src="jquery.infinitescroll.js"></script>
<script>

  $('#box').infinitescroll({

        navSelector  : '#page-nav',            
                       // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
        nextSelector : '#page-nav a',    
                       // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
        itemSelector : '.box'         
                       // selector for all items you'll retrieve
        behaviour: 'twitter'               
      });
</script>

</h:head>



<h:body class="thrColElsHdr">

            <div class="box">   
                // Content

            </div>

<div  id="page-nav">
  <a href="getMoreStatusList.xhtml"></a>
</div>

            <!-- end #mainContent -->
        </div>


    </div>

</h:body>
```

Comment: You are bringing in the infinitescroll plugin script, but not jquery itself. Also, once you have jquery coming in as well, you'll probably want to wrap your script inside the [document ready function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: Included the jquery file and wrapped it inside document ready function but still it isn't firing.

Comment: The only other thing I see is that you are setting up infinitescroll on an element with an id of box (i.e. `$('#box')...`), but the element shown in your markup has a class of box, not id. Try changing to `$('.box').infinitescroll({...});`

Comment: Yup changed to `$('.box') .infinitescroll({...});` but still didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You missed a comma after:

itemSelector : '.box'